# How to determine the currently installed version of sqlPackage

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

We have an installation process that as part of the installation calls SqlPackage to compare a dacpac file against the database for that particular client, and updates any data changes.

The problem we have is that depending on the version of Sql Server and the version of SQL Server Data Tools, we have to pick the correct version of sqlpackage.exe to use.

The current process we use looks in the folder

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Dac\bin\ and loops
>   down through 130, 120, 110 to find the highest available version

Unfortunately though, it is possible that the latest version can be installed in a Visual Studio subfolder

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\130

**Is there any metadata that we can query to figure out what the existing highest version of SqlPackage is on a given server, and where it is to be found?**

Comment: In PATH which version is updated? Because it uses based on the path set in PATH

Comment: How you are running SQLPackage? Are you using Visual Studio Online and PowerShell? Or only the PowerShell?

Comment: Running SqlPackage from a command line generated by a c# program as part of CruiseControl build process. I don't think the path is in my PATH variable

Comment: Then you can directly use the latest path of 14

Comment: No, I don't know which version will be installed on the various clients, and path doesn't contain the info

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53013 If installed from here default location is your second one, but users can change that... USERS you mean you are going to deploy sql server databases on user machines?

Comment: sqlpackage.exe /Version can help assuming the PATH is added unfortunately it's not added by default at times. So use the 140 path and append the switch to see exact build number of it.

Comment: Even though this is a few years old, the default location for sqlpackage installations is C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DAC\bin according to the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-download?view=sql-server-ver15). The /version parameter was also added to check the version number (https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/issues/5032).